# JavaScript/HTML counter

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to write Html code for a small quiz consist of 10 questions, and its written with radio buttons, i want when the user answer or click on the right answer, the counter will increase by one, if he answer the second question right, the counter will become two, so like that..
also when user click on wrong answer i want to increase another counter to display the correct and right answer at the end..

so far i wrote the following html code just for two questions but it does not work.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>QUIZ</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var correct=0;
 var wrong=0;

  function checkans(){
  var ans = document.getElementById("quiz");
  if( ans.elements[1].checked)
  correct++
  else
  wrong++

var ans2 = document.getElementById("quiz2");
if( ans2.elements[0].checked)
 correct++
else
wrong++

 alert("Your correct answers : "+correct+" Your wrong answers : "+wrong)

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="quiz" onsubmit="checkans()" action="">
<p><font color=red>Q1- <font color=black>He ____ it.</p>
 <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="one"/>
 <label>Don't like</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="two"/>
<label>Doesn't like</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="three"/>
<label>Don't likes</label></br>`enter code here`

<form id="quiz2" onsubmit="checkans()" action="">
<p><font color=red>Q2- <font color=black>They _____ here very often.</p>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="four"/>
<label>don't come</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="five"/>
 <label>doesn't comes</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="six"/>
<label>doesn't come</label></br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Grade me"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using multiple forms, and the `<font>` element which was deprecated at least a decade ago.

Comment: Clearly doing the dev in a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: i just used another form to give another id for the second question and match between them, is it wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below, used correct answer checkbox element

```
    <html>
 <head>
 <title>QUIZ</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var correct=0;
 var wrong=0;

  function checkans(){
      var ans = document.getElementById("quiz1CorrectAnswer");
  if( ans.checked)
  correct++
  else
  wrong++

  var ans2 = document.getElementById("quiz2CorrectAnswer");
if( ans2.checked)
 correct++
else
wrong++

 alert("Your correct answers : "+correct+" Your wrong answers : "+wrong)

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="quiz" onsubmit="checkans()" action="">
<p><font color=red>Q1- <font color=black>He ____ it.</p>
 <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="one"/>
 <label>Don't like</label></br>
<input id="quiz1CorrectAnswer" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="two"/>
<label>Doesn't like</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="three"/>
<label>Don't likes</label></br>`enter code here`

<form id="quiz2" onsubmit="checkans()" action="">
<p><font color=red>Q2- <font color=black>They _____ here very often.</p>
<input id="quiz2CorrectAnswer" type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="four"/>
<label>don't come</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="five"/>
 <label>doesn't comes</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton1" value="six"/>
<label>doesn't come</label></br>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Grade me"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried it, it counts the right answer correct, but it doesnt count the wrong answers why!

Comment: it counts correct as well incorrect answers. My logic is if answer is correct then increase CORRECT counter else increase WRONG counter. It works fine if you use code above. let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a function that takes the correct/incorrect value as an argument, then branch accordingly.

```
    function checkAnswer(isCorrect)
    {
       if(isCorrect)
       { correct++; }
       else
       { wrong ++; }
    }
```

I'd do the call on the click of the radio button.  Correct would be

```
checkAnswer(true);
```

Incorrect would be:

```
checkAnswer(false);
```

You'll need to adapt this based on whether or not your user can change their answers, but this should get you started.

Comment: Actually, the validation should happen on submit not by clicking the radio button

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery on Element.("input:checked")

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: I don't see any mention of jQuery in the question.